# what will happen if I use socket.setKeepAlive in Node.js server

Tags: node.js

I just want to ask in `net` module of Node.js because I did not fully understand in the docs. what will happen if I implement the setKeepAlive() ?. what is the behavior of this setKeepAlive() ?

```
var net  = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket){

    socket.setKeepAlive(true,60000); //1 min = 60000 milliseconds.

    socket.on('data',function(data){
        ///receiving data here

    });
    socket.on('end',function(data){

    });

});

server.listen(1333,'127.0.0.1', function () {
      console.log("server is listening in port 1333!");
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `.setKeepAlive()` method enables/disables TCP keep alive.  This is done at the TCP level in the OS, so it is enabled by the node.js socket library, but the keep-alive functionality is actually implemented in the TCP stack in the host OS.

Here's a pretty good summary of what the keep alive feature does: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html.

Here's a piece of that article that should give you an overview:

> The keepalive concept is very simple: when you set up a TCP
>   connection, you associate a set of timers. Some of these timers deal
>   with the keepalive procedure. When the keepalive timer reaches zero,
>   you send your peer a keepalive probe packet with no data in it and the
>   ACK flag turned on. You can do this because of the TCP/IP
>   specifications, as a sort of duplicate ACK, and the remote endpoint
>   will have no arguments, as TCP is a stream-oriented protocol. On the
>   other hand, you will receive a reply from the remote host (which
>   doesn't need to support keepalive at all, just TCP/IP), with no data
>   and the ACK set.
>
> If you receive a reply to your keepalive probe, you can assert that
>   the connection is still up and running without worrying about the
>   user-level implementation. In fact, TCP permits you to handle a
>   stream, not packets, and so a zero-length data packet is not dangerous
>   for the user program.
>
> This procedure is useful because if the other peers lose their
>   connection (for example by rebooting) you will notice that the
>   connection is broken, even if you don't have traffic on it. If the
>   keepalive probes are not replied to by your peer, you can assert that
>   the connection cannot be considered valid and then take the correct
>   action.

Since you are setting keep alive on incoming connections to your server, the effect of the keep alive setting will depend entirely upon what happens with these incoming sockets.  If they are short lived (e.g. they connected, exchange some data and then disconnect like a typical HTTP connection without going inactive for any significant amount of time), then the keep-alive setting will not even come into play.

If, on the other hand, the client connects to the server and holds that connection open for a long time, then the keep-alive setting will come into play and you will see the different behaviors that are called out in the above referenced article.  In addition, if the client is a battery-powered device (phone, tablet, etc...) and it holds a long running connection, then it may consume more battery power and a small bit more bandwidth responding to the regular keep-alive packets because the device has to wake up to receive incoming packets and then has to transmit to send responses.

Comment: so after 1 min the socket server will send probe packet to client ?

Comment: what is the probe packet ?

Comment: I tried to use `setKeepAlive` but I don't see the difference.how do I  test ?

Comment: @jemz - The probe packet is described in the article I linked.  It's an empty data packet that (in the TCP protocol) requires an ACK from the receiving end to verify delivery. If you read the article I linked, I think everything is described there.  You will not see any normal difference in behavior because the keep-alive only triggers a different behavior when something has gone wrong (e.g. a client has rebooted or dropped off the network without shutting down the socket).  If you want to see the keep-alive packets being sent, you could use a network sniffer to see the raw packets being sent.

Comment: @jemz - if you wanted to test the behavior, you could set up a client connection, then after the socket has been idle for a bit, unplug the client from the network and see how soon your server sees that the socket is shut-down.  Without the keep-alive, the server may never notice.  With the keep-alive, it should notice fairly soon.  See the "2.3. Checking for dead peers" section of the above linked document for more description.

Comment: What happens in NodeJS when the keep-alive probe finds out that the connection is interrupted? None of the events indicate this and upon testing, nothing interesting happened (Mac OSX).