# What is the proper way to emit an event with socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to emit an event to the client when a long fucntion comes to an end.
This will show a hidden div with a link - on the client side.

This is the approach i tested:

//server.js

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var http       = require('http').Server(app);
var io         = require('socket.io')(http);

require('./app/routes.js')(app, io);
```

//routes.js

```
app.post('/pst', function(req, res) {
        var url = req.body.convo;

        res.render('processing.ejs');

                myAsyncFunction(url).then(result => {
                    console.log('Async Function completed'); 

                    socket.emit('dlReady', { description: 'Your file is ready!'});

                    //do some other stuff here

        }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.render('error.ejs');
         })
});
```

I get this

```
ERROR: ReferenceError: socket is not defined
```

If i change the socket.emit() line to this:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('dlReady', { description: 'Your file is ready!'});
});
```

Then i don't receive an error, but nothing happens at the client.

This is the client code:

```
<script>
      document.querySelector('.container2').style.display = "none";
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('dlReady', function(data) { //When you receive dlReady event from socket.io, show the link part
        document.querySelector('.container1').style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector('.container2').style.display = "block";
      });
</script>
```

Comment: have you imported, required websocket at the top of your routes.js file?

Comment: No. I don't do any imports in routes.js but i use this: module.exports = function(app, io) {......code here}

Comment: I am not quite sure what are you doing there. Could you maybe edit your question and put your whole routes and server.js files here.

Comment: ok @lazar. i will do it once i am back home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole concept is likely a bit flawed.  Let me state some facts about this environment that you must fully understand before you can follow what needs to happen:

1. When the browser does a POST, there's an existing page in the browser that issues the post.
2. If that POST is issued from a form post (not a post from Javascript in the page), then when you send back the response with `res.render()`, the browser will close down the previous page and render the new page.
3. Any socket.io connection from the previous page will be closed.  If the new page from the `res.render()` has Javascript in it, when that Javascript runs, it may or may not create a new socket.io connection to your server.  In any case, that won't happen until some time AFTER the `res.render()` is called as the browser has to receive the new page, parse it, then run the Javascript in it which has to then connect socket.io to your server again.
4. Remember that servers handle lots of clients.  They are a one-to-many environment.  So, you could easily have hundreds or thousands of clients that all have a socket.io connection to your server.  So, your server can never assume there is ONE socket.io connection and sending to that one connection will go to a particular page.  The server must keep track of N socket.io connections.
5. If the server ever wants to emit to a particular page, it has to create a means of figuring out which exact socket.io connect belongs to the page that it is trying to emit to, get that particular socket and call `socket.emit()` only on that particular socket.  The server can never do this by creating some server-wide variable named `socket` and using that. A multi-user server can never do that.
6. The usual way to "track" a given client as it returns time after time to a server is by setting a unique cookie when the client first connects to your server.  From then on, every connection from that client to your server (until the cookie expires or is somehow deleted by the browser) whether the client is connection for an http request or is making a socket.io connection (which also starts with an http request) will present the cookie and you can then tell which client it is from that cookie.

So, my understanding of your problem is that you'd like to get a form POST from the client, return back to the client a rendered `processing.ejs` and then sometime later, you'd like to communicate with that rendered page in the client via socket.io.  To do that, the following steps must occur.

1. Whenever the client makes the POST to your server, you must make sure there is a unique cookie sent back to that client.  If the cookie already exists, you can leave it.  If it does not exist, you must create a new one.  This can be done manually, or you can use `express-session` to do it for you.  I'd suggest using `express-session` because it will make the following steps easier and I will outline steps assuming you are using `express-session`.
2. Your processing.ejs page must have Javascript in it that makes a socket.io connection to your server and registers a message listener for your "dlready" message that your server will emit.
3. You will need a top-level `io.on('connection', ...)` on your server that puts the `socket` into the session object.  Because the client can connect from multiple tabs, if you don't want that to cause trouble, you probably have to maintain an array of sockets in the session object.
4. You will need a `socket.on('disconnect', ...)` handler on your server that can remove a socket from the session object it's been stored in when it disconnects.
5. In your `app.post()` handler, when you are ready to send the `dlready` message, you will have to find the appropriate `socket` for that browser in the session object for that page and emit to that socket(s).  If there are none because the page you rendered has not yet connected, you will have to wait for it to connect (this is tricky to do efficiently).

If the POST request comes in from Javascript in the page rather than from a form post, then things are slightly simpler because the browser won't close the current page and start a new page and thus the current socket.io connection will stay connected.  You could still completely change the page visuals using client-side Javascript if you wanted.  I would recommend this option.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for theis comprehensive answer. It seems like a very cumbersome situation, having to deal with session cookies now. But, another option is there, based on your idea to send something trivila to the response to keep it alive. I asked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387183/send-content-at-intervals-in-javascript-node-js/ and user iximiuz suggested i use setKeepAlive(). I went to research this and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365250/what-will-happen-if-i-use-socket-setkeepalive-in-node-js-server, only to realize that you have writen what

Comment: I was reading all this time! So, do you think i can keep Heroku happy by using socket.setKeepAlive()? The idea is that the asynchronouns function will run this, so it keeps Heroky happy? Can this be implemented from the async function?

Comment: @user1584421 - No.  I don't think that will have anything to do with this question.

Comment: I know, i am just saying, since it was your idea to keep the connection alive. Because the answer to this question is hard to implement, maybe i should try your idea to kepp the connection alive. So will setKeepAlive() work? Do you think it can keep Heroku satisfies?

Comment: No.  Keepalive won't help you.  Is your POST coming from an Ajax call via Javascript in your web page or from a browser form post?  I have an idea for how to solve this, but need to now which type of POST it is.

Comment: It is from a form post.

Comment: Is it `processing.ejs` that has the socket.io message handler for `dlReady` in it?  The whole picture of what you're trying to make work here is not entirely clear, but is required to understand how to solve it.

Comment: Correct! When i was testing (unsuccelfully) socket.io, this is the method i used.

Comment: @user1584421 - Approximately how long does your async operation take to run before you want to send `dlReady`?