# Send content at intervals in JavaScript/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

I want to execute a particular line of code at timed intervals. The line will be `res.write("")`, to keep a connection alive.

This is similar to hardware interrupts in embedded systems.

Is it possible to have a function that inside will run my code, but at 20 seconds period to execute one particular line of code?

Comment: You might want to take a look at web sockets.

Comment: Do they offer this functionality?

Comment: take a look  to  setInterval()  function

Answer (score 4):

The code `res.write("")` not necessary will send something to the wire, since the payload is empty. What you might need is [`TCP keepalive`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay) functionality.

```
 res.connection.setKeepAlive(true, 20000)
```

Comment: My code consists of a function that takes a lot of time to finish and Heroku throws an H12 timeout error for more than 30 seconds of not serving a response. I hope this line will trick Heroku. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The link you provided, does not contain any res.connection.setKeepAlive() function. It only caontains, socket.setKeepAlive([enable][, initialDelay]). Is this the one you are referring to?

Comment: Sure, res.connection is just my guess how one can access the underlying socket object having a reference to a request. You can also try req.connection or look for the information about accessing of the connection in the framework you use.

Comment: So you wrote res.connection.setKeepAlive(true, 20000), instead of socket.setKeepAlive(true, 5000);, because i am using the express framework. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can use setInterval

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

```
setInterval(() => res.write(""), 20000);
```

Comment: While not 'wrong' per se, this really isn't a great way to keep a connection alive.

Comment: I absolutely agree to that.  I was responding more to the beginning of the question which is `I want to execute a code, but at timed intervals`

Comment: If you decide to go with setInterval, don’t forget to close interval after sending the response.