# When should I use (or not use) the keepAlive option of the Node.js http Agent?

Tags: node.js

I recently had a problem with a Node.js http client in my application that was making so many requests to a remote API that it was exhausting the operating system's available ephemeral ports, triggering `connect EADDRNOTAVAIL` errors from some requests. I eventually discovered that I could eliminate this problem by making the requests using an `http.Agent` with [options](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#new-agentoptions) `keepAlive: true` and `maxSockets` set to some reasonable value. E.g.:

```
new http.Agent({keepAlive: true, maxSockets: 25})
```

This change seems to have eliminated my `EADDRNOTAVAIL` errors without any negative effects, but I'm wary of it because the `keepAlive` option defaults to `false` (and `maxSockets` defaults to `Infinity`). The fact that the default is `false` suggests that there is some cost or downside to setting `keepAlive: true`. I'd like to understand what the downside is so that I can understand in what situations I should turn `keepAlive` on, and when I should leave it off.

Comment: is there a reason you are making so many requests? can you not wait for some to finish before continuing on? [`keepAlive`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#new-agentoptions) only reuses sockets instead of instantiating new ones for every request, the downside here would be that the sockets will be around even after you have finished the requests, if you continue to use them i dont see a downside

Comment: Yes, there is a good reason I am making so many requests; I can probably reduce the volume but it would take significant code changes so I need to work with what I've got for now. I'm not sure what you mean by, "can you not wait for some to finish before continuing on?" The problem is that each request only takes ~1ms, but if I don't re-use the socket, the operating system [withholds the request's ephemeral port from use for 60s](https://serverfault.com/questions/23385) after it's done. I do wait for each request to complete, but my process can't wait minutes for used ports to come back.

Comment: You have to be making an insane amount of request to run in to that kind of problem, if other options are out due to "significant code changes" and this one works without any known negatives.. what's the question here?

Comment: The question is, are there any _unknown_ negatives? Any negatives that I'm not perceiving? Another way of putting it would be, if there are no negatives, why does `keepAlive` default to `false`? You mentioned above, "the downside here would be that the sockets will be around even after you have finished the requests". That sounds like the beginning of an answer, I'd just want to understand better what about "the sockets be[ing] around" is bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what will happen if I use socket.setKeepAlive in Node.js server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365250/what-will-happen-if-i-use-socket-setkeepalive-in-node-js-server)

Comment: The linked question doesn't answer mine very directly, but I think the [document linked from there](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html) does. In particular, "Keepalive is non-invasive, and in most cases, if you're in doubt, you can turn it on without the risk of doing something wrong. But do remember that it generates extra network traffic, which can have an impact on routers and firewalls." Would you like to create an answer based on this discussion so I can accept it, @about14sheep?

Comment: i summarized our conversation here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the conversation in comments to an answer to close out the question.

The [`keepAlive`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#new-agentoptions) reuses sockets instead of instantiating new ones for every request, the "downside" here would be that the sockets will be around even after you have finished the requests and continue communicating over the network.

This "downside" is actually the functionality you are looking for. Since closing them then reopening them have a negative impact, you want to keep these communication channels open.

To further put someones (who has the same question) mind at ease, as @mactyr noted in the comments above (and based on [this how-to blog post](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html)), `keepAlive` is non-invasive and can be turned on without the risk of doing something wrong.